# Unity3D - Using AddRelativeForce to push an object forever in zero gravity environment

Tags: unity, c#, physics

Ok, I use `AddRelativeForce` to basically push an object. But it suppose to keep flying and keep accelerating as I hold down the key because I didn't set gravity. I just started Unity3D last month, so pls give me some advice.

```
// Force of individual thrusters
public float thrusterForce = 10000;
// Whether or not to add force at position which introduces torque
public bool addForceAtPosition = false;

private bool thrusterIsActive = false;  
private Transform objectTransform;
private Rigidbody objectParentRigidbody;

void FixedUpdate() {
    if (thrusterIsActive) {
        if (addForceAtPosition) {
            objectParentRigidbody.AddForceAtPosition (objectTransform.up * thrusterForce, objectTransform.position);
        } else {
            objectParentRigidbody.AddRelativeForce (Vector3.forward * thrusterForce);               
        }
    }       
}
```

Comment: What problem are you having? What are you trying to solve?

Comment: @DMGregory The object slowly decelerate when I release the key. It want the object keep flying endlessly and accelerate while I'm holding down the "forward" key. Like spaceship in the space.

Comment: So you want if you press the then your object should increase its speed? Let say the speed is 50 when you release the key, and you want to retain speed to 50, right? And when you press the key again then speed should increase from 50 to higher value, right?

Comment: @HamzaHasan Yes, absolutely, just like you're in the space.

Comment: The reason I asked about this when it was first posted is normally you shouldn't have to do anything at all. Unity defaults new Rigidbody components to have a linear drag value of 0, so once they're in motion, they'll stay in motion until they hit something. I wouldn't expect to see this deceleration effect unless 1. The user deliberately added drag, 2.The user had useGravity enabled and was flying against the direction of gravity, or 3. Another script was exerting forces on this same object, none of which is apparent in this question.

Answer (score 0):

Then I'd suggest to play with velocity directly. It'd be easy to handle. I writing an untested code for doing the same but with velocity on Space Bar. Give it a try if this would help you.

```
Rigidbody _rb;
Vector3 _velocity = Vector3.zero;
float _speed = 0.1f;

void Start ()
{
    _rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody> ();
}

void Update ()
{
    _rb.velocity = Vector3.Scale (_velocity, transform.forward);
    if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.Space))
        _velocity += Vector3.one * _speed;
}
```

**Update**

To do the same in your code, you can try the code below. But let me know if you get any problem as it is untested.

```
// Force of individual thrusters
public float thrusterForce = 10000;
// Whether or not to add force at position which introduces torque
public bool addForceAtPosition = false;

private bool thrusterIsActive = false;  
private Transform objectTransform;
private Rigidbody objectParentRigidbody;
private Vector3 _velocity = Vector3.zero;

void FixedUpdate() {

    if (thrusterIsActive) {
        if (addForceAtPosition) {
            objectParentRigidbody.AddForceAtPosition (objectTransform.up * thrusterForce, objectTransform.position);
        } else {
            objectParentRigidbody.AddRelativeForce (Vector3.forward * thrusterForce);               
        }
        _velocity = objectParentRigidbody.velocity;
    } 
    else
        objectParentRigidbody.velocity = _velocity;      
}
```

Comment: I can see your code is definitely working, but I want to work with force because it's easier to deal with physics. Is it possible to somehow change my code that work exactly your code do.

Comment: Check the edits

Comment: The speed is slower than before, and instead of the slowly decelerating effect, the object just stop right after I release the key.

Comment: Ok, let me review it

Comment: It should work, check if you are missing very first line of update??

Comment: I checked it, I even replaced the code.

Comment: Check it again..